# Unrecoverable failure in Jinja templating: no loader for this environment specified. Have you configured your variables?

Tags: jinja2, lint, sqlfluff

I have set up sqlfluff linter . While comiting the sql file i am getting this error
Unrecoverable failure in Jinja templating: no loader for this environment specified. Have you configured your   variables?   https://docs.sqlfluff.com/en/latest/configuration.html .

Any changes i need to do in .sqlfluff file ?

i need to commit the file

Comment: This question would benefit from a [mcve]: show us both your sqlfluff configuration and an example sql files that generates this error when you lint it with sqlfluff.